# Flask routes other than '/' not being served by apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, raspberry-pi3, wsgi

So I should preface this by saying I am new to Flask, Apache, and web serving so I apologize in advance for my ignorance.

I am trying to set up a remote data logging project with Raspberry Pi 3. I am capturing data to a SQL database then serving that info via Apache in the form of interactive plots.

I have been trying to do things with flask lately as I like how flexible it is. I have successfully setup flask and Apache and have both serving hello worlds. I then setup wsgi to serve the flask routes via Apache and was able to get hello world to work. I then replicated this example ( [PART 1](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Raspberry-Pi-System-Information-Web-Application-with-Python-and-Flask.aspx) / [PART 2](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Serving-a-Python-Flask-Web-Application-via-Apache-Webserver-in-Raspberry-Pi.aspx) ) with success.

[image]

I then wanted to connect the restart button to a flask route that would actually restart the Pi. I am able to get this to work in the dev environment 'localhost:5000'. If instead I navigate to the Pi from the web I am able load the sysinfo page but the route to the restart fails with a 404 error.

> "Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you
>   entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

Below is the route from index.py:

```
@app.route("/sysinfo/restart_now", methods=['GET','POST'])
def restart_now():
    subprocess.call("delayed-reboot",shell=True)
    return render_template("restart_now.html")
```

And the button code serving the route in the index.html template:

```
     <form action="/sysinfo/restart_now" method="post">
    <button name="restart_now" onclick="return confirm('Do you wish to shutdown your system ?')" class="button button-primary">Reboot Pi</button>
     </form>
```

And the php countdown in the restart_now.html template:

```
  <p>Sysinfo will reload automatically in <span id="counter">45</span> second(s).</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function countdown() {
      var i = document.getElementById('counter');
      if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
      location.href = '/sysinfo';

      }
      if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)>0) {
      i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;

      }            
  }
  setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
  </script>
```

this is the bash script delayed-reboot which I have placed in /usr/local/bin:

```
#!/bin/bash
( sleep 5 ; sudo reboot ) &
```

and this is the wsgi configure I am using:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess sysinfo user=pi group=www-data threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /sysinfo /var/www/sysinfo/sysinfo.wsgi
<Directory "/var/www/sysinfo">
    WSGIProcessGroup sysinfo
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/www/sysinfo/logs/error.log
```

and the sysinfo.wsgi file:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/sysinfo')
from index import app as application
```

Any help understanding what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

-Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't working because you are mounting the application at a sub URL in Apache, but your route in Flask also has the mount point in it. This means the URL you use would need to be `/sysinfo/sysinfo/restart_now`.

You either need to use in the Flask route just `/restart_now`, or change the Apache configuration to use:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /sysinfo /var/www/sysinfo/sysinfo.wsgi/sysinfo
```

The addition of the trailing `/sysinfo` on last argument fiddles things so that the Flask application still sees the mount point as part of `PATH_INFO`, which is what Flask routes off.

BTW, you don't need `WSGIScriptReloading On` as that is the default anyway.

Comment: Thank you. It took me a minute but I did eventually figure this out and came back to explain and saw your reply. 

Btw - what is a good way to debug flask/java/html code? 

What I ended up doing was making another test page template and then printing in text {{ url_for("restart_now") }} which after doing that it became apparent what was going on. I also realized I should have been using {{url_for(...)}} instead of direct href's and fixed that as well. 

I have had some success with chrome>more tools>dev tools but am new to this.