# Flask URL Pathing Issues

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I'm new to Flask, so bear with me. I've successfully got my website up & running publicly, but when it comes to using URL pathing, my server keeps giving me "Not Found" errors. Resulting in only the default index.html file being able to be edited/displayed. Currently using WSGI/Apache/Flask.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return ("I've been dead inside for years.")

@app.route('/testing')
def testing():
    return render_template('testing.html')

if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My WSGI.conf file is setup as so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName {my domain IP here}
            ServerAdmin {my email here}
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And my WSGI file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = '{my secret key here}'
```

I keep seeing mentions of root directories perhaps being the issue, but I've found no clear answer about this, I've been searching online for quite a while now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you specify where the "not found" errors occur? Is your path not to be found, or it can't find your template?

Comment: It occurs when trying to loadwww.mysite.xyz/testing and www.mysite.xyz/testing/ both. The error is as follows:

    Not Found
    The requested URL /testing was not found on this server.

Thats literally it. I figured it would be something to solve like a typo, etc. but its not looking that way to me. Template files don't load in at all.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Apache, I prefer Nginx. But consider reading these two pages: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/mod_wsgi/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153448/flask-routes-other-than-not-being-served-by-apache